# Make Editable (In Place) Table Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a page that shows a quote (id, purpose of quote, etc) for a customer with a table also on the page that shows products a customer is wanting to buy that are in the quote.

I need to make the product table editable, and I do not want to use a gem because I would really like to know how this actually works.

So, here is what my page looks like so far:

```
<h1>Edit Quote</h1>

     <%= form_for(@quote) do |q| %>

        <p>
            <%= q.label :service_tech %>
            <%= q.text_field :service_tech %>
        </p>

        <p>
            <%= q.label :purpose %>
            <%= q.text_field :purpose %>
        </p>

        <p>
            <%= q.submit %>
        </p>
<% end %>


<p>Products</p>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Product/Part</th>  
    <th>Unit/Mdl</th>
    <th>Description</th>  
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Total</th>  
</tr>   
<% @products.each do |p| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= p.product_part %></td>
        <td><%= p.unit_mdl %></td>
        <td><%= p.description %></td>
        <td><%= p.quantity %></td>
        <td><%= p.price %></td>
        <td><%= p.total %></td>
        <td>[<%= link_to "edit", edit_product_path(q) %>]</td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

So, what I am wanting to do is remove my link to edit my product, and create the ability to edit the product in place and click a save button that saves the product.

I assumed that I would create some jquery function that when a save button is clicked the jquery grabs the new data from the table and passes the parameters to my update definition in my products controller. However, I do not know how to get the information from the table, make the table editable, and post the data I need to update the correct record.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Even if you don't want to use a gem, you will probably need a javascript plugin for that. I would recommend you to take a look at: https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am really trying to do this from scratch.